# Reload проекта после pre-build event

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В .NET проекте настроен pre-build event который генерирует несколько исходных файлов, необходимо что бы эти файлы были включены в проект до того как начнется сборка.
Я прочел здесь что можно в .csproj-файле указать папку содержимое которой будет включено в проект(и это действительно работает), например
`<Content Include="AutoCodegen\**" />`
включает в проект все файлы из папки AutoCodegen, но это происходит только после перезагрузки проекта (например перезапуска студии).
Есть ли способ сделать reload проекту после pre-buil ивента или может есть какой другой способ добиться моей цели ?
Спасибо.

Comment: А количество файлов динамическое или фиксированное?

Comment: Вы делаете что-то не то. Генерируйте файлы и компилируйте их отдельно. Или используйте T4.

Comment: В pre-build ивенте я использую Apache Thrift (он генерирует файлы исходних кодов на основе некоторого описания) затем эти файлы используются в проекте. Количество файлов динамическое.

Comment: @Aleksey вы мне не ответили. Количество файлов фиксированное?

Comment: @V.Dmitriy ответил же "Количество файлов динамическое." Видимо заранее добавить эти файлы не получиться т.к. не известно сколько их.

Comment: @Мурад а, извините. Недосмотрел

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо вместо pre-build event использовать свой target в файле проекта. Внутри можно использовать задачу [`Exec`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/x8zx72cd.aspx).

После выполнения этой задачи можно подменить список входных файлов для компиляции:

```
<Target Name="ВашТаргет" BeforeTargets="BeforeCompile">
  <Exec ... />

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="AutoCodegen\**" />
    <Compile Include="AutoCodegen\**" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Подобные файлы, добавленные динамически, не будут видны в списке файлов проекта - но будут учитываться при компиляции.

**Ограничение.** Данный способ несовместим с R# - он наотрез отказывается видеть динамически добавленные в проект файлы.